# Which is the most common and efficient way to implement the event handling class in Java?

Tags: java, events, awt, event-listener

As per the title, which is the best and most efficient way to implement event handling?

1. creating the listener object as an inner class
2. by using the `this` keyword
3. using an anonymous class for the event listener

Comment: If the listener is short, you can create an anonymous inner class by using a lambda.  If the listener is longer or more complicated, create a separate class implementing `ActionListener`.

Comment: Even better, implement [Action](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Observer pattern.
For example:

```
    public class Observer {
        private String state;

        public void update(String state) {
            this.setState(state);
        }
    }

    public class Observed {
        private String state;
        private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<>();

        public void addObserver(Observer observer) {
            this.observers.add(observer);
        }

        public void removeObserver(Observer observer) {
            this.observers.remove(observer);
        }

        public void setState(String state) {
            this.state = state;
            for (Observer observer : this.observers) {
                observer.update(this.state);
            }
        }
    }
```